# How can I receive messages sent to a PID which running inside a gen_server

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-supervisor, ejabberd-module

- I have a ejabberd server
- I have a custom module, `my_apns_module.erl` which is run by ejabberd server like this:

  ```
  start_link(Host, Opts) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?PROCNAME),
    ?GEN_SERVER:start_link({local, Proc}, ?MODULE,
                           [Host, Opts], []).
  start(Host, Opts) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?PROCNAME),
    ChildSpec = {Proc, {?MODULE, start_link, [Host, Opts]},
                 temporary, 1000, worker, [?MODULE]},
    supervisor:start_child(ejabberd_sup, ChildSpec).

  stop(Host) ->
    Proc = gen_mod:get_module_proc(Host, ?PROCNAME),
    ?GEN_SERVER:call(Proc, stop),
    supervisor:delete_child(ejabberd_sup, Proc),
    ok.

  init([Host, _Opts]) ->
     ...

  handle_call(stop, _From, State) ->
    {stop, normal, ok, State}.

  handle_cast(_Msg, State) -> {noreply, State}.

  handle_info(#offline_msg{us = _UserServer,
            from = From, to = To, packet = Packet} = _Msg, State) ->
    ...

  handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

  terminate(_Reason, State) ->
    Host = State#state.host,
    ok.

  code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) -> {ok, State}.
  ```
- Inside init I run another APNs application to send push notifictions. https://github.com/inaka/apns4erl

  ```
  init([Host, _Opts]) ->
        apns:start(),
        case apns:connect(cert, ?APNS_CONNECTION) of
             {ok, PID} -> ?INFO_MSG("apns connection successful with PID ~p~n", [PID]);
             {error, timeout} -> ?ERROR_MSG("apns connection unsuccessful reason timed out", [])
        end,
        {ok, #state{host = Host}}.
  ```
- This is working as I can send notifications.
- Now the documentation (https://github.com/inaka/apns4erl) says:

> If network goes down or something unexpected happens the gun
> connection with APNs will go down. In that case apns4erl will send a
> message `{reconnecting, ServerPid}` to the client process, that means
> apns4erl lost the connection and it is trying to reconnect. Once the
> connection has been recover a `{connection_up, ServerPid}` message will
> be send.

My question is:

- what code should I write inside `my_apns_module.erl` to receive `{reconnecting, ServerPid}` or `{connection_up, ServerPid}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages sent to a gen_server process, e.g. `GenServerPid ! {ok, 10}`}, are handled by:

```
handle_info(Msg, State)
```

So, you could do something like this:

```
handle_info({reconnecting, ServerPid}=Msg, State) ->
     %%do something here, like log Msg or change State;
handl_info({connection_up, ServerPid}=Msg, State) ->
     %%do something here, like log Msg or change State;   
handle_info(#offline_msg{us = _UserServer,
          from = From, to = To, packet = Packet} = _Msg, State) ->
     %%do something.
```

**Response to comment:**

This is your current code:

```
init([Host, _Opts]) ->
      apns:start(),
      case apns:connect(cert, ?APNS_CONNECTION) of
           {ok, PID} -> ?INFO_MSG("apns connection successful with PID ~p~n", [PID]);
           {error, timeout} -> ?ERROR_MSG("apns connection unsuccessful reason timed out", [])
      end,
      {ok, #state{host = Host}}.
```

You could change that to something like this:

```
init([Host, _Opts]) ->
    spawn(?MODULE, start_apns, []),
    ...


start_apns() ->

          apns:start(),
          case apns:connect(cert, ?APNS_CONNECTION) of
               {ok, PID} -> ?INFO_MSG("apns connection successful with PID ~p~n", [PID]);
               {error, timeout} -> ?ERROR_MSG("apns connection unsuccessful reason timed out", [])
          end,
          apns_loop().

apns_loop() ->
    receive
        {reconnecting, ServerPid} -> %%do something;
        {connection_up, ServerPid} -> %% do something;
        Other -> %% do something
    end,
    apns_loop().
```

After you start the apns process, the apns process will enter a loop and wait for messages.

Comment: Hold on...message is not sent to gen_server, lets say GenServerPID but to a process running inside gen_server, lets say PID. That process was started by the statement {OK, PID} = apns:connect(cert, ?APNS_CONNECTION). So the GenServerPID was started by ejabberd and PID was started via apns:connect inside my_apns_module. So as I understand that handle_info will handle messages sent by ejabberd server to GenServerPID. Would it also handle messages sent to PID?

Comment: *So as I understand that handle_info will handle messages sent by ejabberd server to GenServerPID. Would it also handle messages sent to PID?*-- Messages sent to a non-gen_server process need to be handled by a receive clause.

Comment: @GJain, I added an example of what you can do.

Comment: I am sorry ... I have another question..spawn will start a new process, lets say spawnPID....but the apns sends the message to PID, so (is apns_loop handling spawnPID or PID) or (is spawnPID == PID)?

Comment: GJain,  Which process is PID?  *In that case apns4erl will send a message {reconnecting, ServerPid} to the client process* -- You have to figure out which process is the `client process`.